# '@media only ' and '@media all' difference

Tags: css, media-queries

I just started learning about responsive web design and I get the difference between 
`@media only screen`,
`@media screen` and 
`@media`  but I've also seen some sites use 
`@media all`, and I'd like to know what difference or similarity it has with the others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you have an explanation about all the media types

http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/media.html

Hope this helps